# Notepad .LOG only saves log time when opened manually

Tags: c#, notepad

I have a text file that begins with *.LOG* inside and each time I manually edit the file and save, the edit time gets logged.

I tried replicating the same concept using StreamWriter, however the edit time no longer gets logged. The time is logged only when I update the file manually. What could be the reason for this?

My Code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("log.txt");
string myText = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt");
writer.WriteLine(myText+ Environment.NewLine+"Automated Test");
writer.Flush();
write.Close();
```

Screenshot:

[image: Log File]

Comment: Well your code doesn't mention writing the current time anywhere... if you want to do that, you need to write the code to do it. This isn't something that just happens automatically. (It's unclear what does that when you edit it manually - it sounds like there's some context you haven't told us.) I'd also encourage you to look at `File.AppendAllText` etc rather than reading all of the current content only to write it out again.

Comment: @DaisyShipton this is the entire context. Please try it manually yourself. I think it is a Notepad feature. Only works manually.

Comment: Yup, looks like it's part of notepad.exe - certainly a feature I've never seen before. It's not an inherent part of text file storage. If you want to include a timestamp when you append to the file, you'll need to do that yourself in code.

Comment: For anyone interested, see https://www.groovypost.com/howto/5-groovy-things-about-notepad-exe/ for more info about the Notepad feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of Notepad itself. It's not something that happens automatically when the file is written from anything else.

You'll need to append the timestamp yourself. I'd suggest using `File.AppendAllLines` rather than reading the whole file and then rewriting it though. For example:

```
string[] lines =
{
    // Short date/time pattern in system culture, using system time zone
    DateTime.Now.ToString("g"), 
    "First new line",
    "Second new line"
};
File.AppendAllLines("log.txt", lines);
```